# Show jquery mobile dialog only once on startup (web app)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, web-applications

My problem is that following code works fine (dialog show once on startup), but when I navigate to another page (with standard ajax activated), and then navigate back to the first page, the dialog is showing again (and then in a loop manner when I click "dismiss").

What am I doing wrong?

Code looks like that:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#pageindex', function(event) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#dialog').click();
            $('#dialog').remove();
        },1000);
});
```

Comment: `pageinit` fires once only. Are you using multi-html files or single page? Try replacing `.on` with `.one`.

Comment: I use multi-html files. Have to test a little bit more, but it seems that it works with `one`, very cool. You could make your comment as an answer, so I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a quick fix, replace `.on` with`.one`. However, normally `pageinit` event should fire once only, so there must be something causing it to fire multiple times.

Comment: When using multi HTML template (multiple pages) then the first page is always cached in DOM. But the pages except the first page are loaded and cleaned out from DOM after you leave them. That's why pageinit is fired more than once. It's the normal behavior.

Comment: This happens when navigating back to homepage where dialog is called. Also, the event is attached to `#pageindex`, so it fires only for that specific page. It doesn't occur in other pages. @TolisEmmanouilidis

Comment: I mean that he has to check whether the `#pageindex` page remains in DOM while he is navigating to the next pages. In multiple HTML template, the pages (except the first page) are loaded and cleaned out from DOM after leaving them. In a such case where the page is removed and re-added in DOM, the `pageinit` event will fire again.

Comment: @TolisEmmanouilidis yes true, you are right. Also it depends where the JS code is placed, whether inside the first page or an external JS file.

Answer (score 0):

The following code is executed once on single/multipage page and multiple pages approach:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#pageindex', function (event) {
    $(this).off(event);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#dialog').click();
        $('#dialog').remove();
    }, 1000);
});
```